# How to compare Null values from the database column

Tags: sql-server, null

I have record in my table where Name column has Null value.. and I want to update that record using below query..
My sql query is:

```
set @Name=NUll;

update emp set name="gaurav" where name=@Name
```

When I run this query.. It will not update the record.. It does not compare the value `Null` to column value

How can this be done?

Comment: No I can't use this.. because @Name has sometime value, and if value contains then update basis on that value.. either it is Null or it has value..

Comment: Try out `update emp set name="gaurav" where isnull(name,'')=''`

Comment: @PavanKumar That updates names that are empty strings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SET @Name = NULL;

UPDATE emp
SET name="gaurav"
WHERE    (@Name IS NULL     AND name IS NULL)
      OR (@Name IS NOT NULL AND name = @Name)
```

Comment: The `OR (@Name IS NOT NULL AND name = @Name)` can be simplified to `OR (name = @Name)`

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use following condition with `ISNULL()`

```
SET @Name = NULL;

UPDATE emp SET name='gaurav' WHERE ISNULL(@Name,'XXXXXXX')=ISNULL(Name,'XXXXXXX');
```

Where `'XXXXXXX'` is a unique string constant which can't exist in EMP table;

Comment: Apart from the issue of finding a magic string that can't possibly appear in the data this approach prevents the possibility of using an index on `name` to locate the matching row(s)

Answer (score 1):

Tests with null values are always false in SQL, except IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.
you should add a IS NULL clause to your WHERE:

```
WHERE name = @name
**OR (name IS NULL and @name IS NULL)**
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this `UPDATE emp SET name = "gaurav" WHERE (@name IS NULL AND name IS NULL)`

Comment: The OP is using a variable.

Comment: No I can't use this.. because @Name has sometime value, and if value contains then update basis on that value.. either it is Null or it has value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing MartinSmith 
@user2003615 you can refer to ta.speot.is's answer.

Answer (score -3):

As per my SQL Knowledge u can store **`NULL`** in a variable, but can't use it for comparing

```
update emp set name="gaurav" where name is Null
```

Comment: The OP is using a variable.

Comment: @MartinSmith have you serially downvoted all this answers ??

Comment: as per my SQL Knowledge u can store **`NULL`** in a variable but can't use it for comparing

Comment: Actully this parameter in stored procedure...

Comment: @Dhaval The answers didn't really answer the question, so if Martin Smith did serially downvote then there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @user2003615 So don't use it.

Comment: @Dhaval - I downvoted all the FGITW answers that missed the point about the variable and upvoted the one that didn't.

Comment: @Luv **u can store NULL in a variable** in sql server

Comment: No I can't use this.. because @Name has sometime value, and if value contains then update basis on that value.. either it is Null or it has value.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24914/0

Comment: @MartinSmith and  ta.speot.is  .. i dont mind with down vote but just want to know .. and about the point i got that thing so i already deleted my answer