# WHERE clause using values that could be NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I need to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @firstname VARCHAR(35)
DECLARE @lastname VARCHAR(35)

SELECT *
FROM Customers 
WHERE Firstname = @firstname AND Lastname = @lastname
```

The problem is that `@firstname` and `@lastname` could sometimes be `NULL`. In those cases, the query above would fail to find matching rows because `NULL` is never equal to `NULL`.

If one of these variables is `NULL`, I'd like to return a match if the corresponding value in the database is also `NULL`. But, of course, SQL Server uses `IS` to compare for `NULL`. And if either value is `NULL` in the example above, it is not considered a match.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to simplify a NULL compare of 2 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138082/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-a-null-compare-of-2-values)

Comment: @Charlieface: Not really. The answer that I accepted answered it much better.

Comment: @JonathanWood actually Charlieface's suggest *is* better than mine (IMO). Much simpler and scalable.

Comment: As you do. I find my version much less cumbersome. @DaleK I don't think performance is much different in most instances, just much neater, especially with a lot of comparisons.

Comment: @Charlieface to be fair though, I don't think its a dupe, OP is asking *how* to do it whereas suggested dupe is asking *how to improve*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare Null values from the database column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951099/how-to-compare-null-values-from-the-database-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use AND/OR logic e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE ((Firstname IS NULL AND @firstname IS NULL) OR Firstname = @firstname)
AND ((Lastname IS NULL AND @lastname IS NULL) OR Lastname = @lastname);
```

Comment: Were you aware of the `INTERSECT/EXCEPT` trick? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139209/14868997

Comment: See below and Paul White's article. Note by the way that your version also compiles down to `IS` in the query plan

Answer (score 3):

**You can leverage `INTERSECT` in a correlated subquery to do this.** This works because set-based operations compare `NULL`s as equal.

The compiler will [automatically compile this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139209/14868997) down to an `IS` comparison, there should not be any performance hit.

```sql
DECLARE @firstname VARCHAR(35)
DECLARE @lastname VARCHAR(35)

SELECT *
FROM Customers c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT c.Firstname, c.Lastname
             INTERSECT
             SELECT @firstname, @lastname)
```

The logic is: for every row, create a one-row virtual table with the two values, intersect it with the two variables and there must be a result.

For a `<>` semantic, change `EXISTS` to `NOT EXISTS`, rather than changing to `EXCEPT`, I find the former optimizes better.

[All credit to Paul White](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html) for this trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ISNULL()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to return a replacement value when `@firstname`, `@lastname`, etc. are `NULL`. If both of the default values at each side of the equals operator are the same, the expression will be evaluated to true. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers 
WHERE ISNULL(Firstname, '') = ISNULL(@firstname, '')
    AND ISNULL(Lastname, '') = ISNULL(@lastname, '')
```

My solution assumes there are no empty strings in the data. However, if you do expect empty strings in some of the values, you can change the default value of  `ISNULL()` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

**A new option is now available in SQL Server 2022.**

You can now use the [**`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) syntax:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.Firstname IS NOT DISTINCT FROM @firstname
  AND c.Lastname  IS NOT DISTINCT FROM @lastname;
```

This compiles into an `IS` comparison underneeath, and is very efficient.