# How to update a value in column based on value from other table in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables match_score and match_condition
I want to update table match_condition and set values of innings, first_4, etc.

Here's the example in which I am trying to update table match_condition with innings value from match_score whenever both of them is not matched

```
UPDATE a
SET a.innings = b.innings
FROM  match_condition    a
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM match_score  order by time_stamp desc ) b  
ON  a.matchid = b.matchid
WHERE  a.innings != b.innings
```

match_score table

```
matchid   time_stamp              overs ball  run  team_score   wicket  innings
50821   2021-04-22 10:52:58.640     20  6      1      137         0      1
50821   2021-04-22 10:52:58.637     20  5      1      136         0      1
50821   2021-04-22 10:52:58.633     20  4      0      135         1      1
```

match_condition table

```
matchid seriesid    match_time            innings  powerplay_over first_50 first_100 first_150 first_200 first_4 first_6 first_wicket
50820   2780      2021-04-19 18:44:12.360  NULL     NULL            NULL      NULL     NULL      NULL     NULL   NULL     NULL
50821   2780      2021-04-20 10:00:06.827  NULL     NULL            NULL      NULL     NULL      NULL     NULL   NULL     NULL
```

I made changes according to answers here , but still its showing 0 row affected

Comment: You have a `WHERE` immediately after your `CASE` expression; that isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Also should be `UPDATE a` use the alias, not the table name

Comment: @Charlieface I have tried using alias in Update , the query is getting executed but  0 rows affected.

Comment: `a.innings != b.innings` will never return true because `b.innings` is null see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202766/where-clause-using-values-that-could-be-null/67203618#67203618

Comment: I have used this ```WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT match_condition .[innings] INTERSECT  match_score .[innings])```  , but still not working

Comment: Wait , do you want `INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM match_score  order by time_stamp desc ) b` to match *per `matchid`* then you need an `apply`

Comment: @Shubh check my updated answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If value innings in `match_condition` will never be -1 this query will finish your job:

```
UPDATE 
    match_condition 
SET 
    match_condition.innings = a.innings
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 innings, matchid FROM match_score ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) a
WHERE 
    match_condition.matchid = a.matchid
AND 
    ISNULL(match_condition.innings, -1) <> a.innings
```

If you think that value can be somehow -1, just change in ISNULL operator value to sam 'unreal' number.

Here is [DB FIDDLE demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df67fba987233443dff9476e83e21162)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using a subquery

```
UPDATE match_condition
SET    match_condition.innings =
       (
              SELECT
                     CASE
                            WHEN match_condition.innings != b.innings THEN match_condition.innings
                            ELSE b.innings
                     END
                     FROM match_score b
              WHERE  match_condition.matchid = b.matchid
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your query would appear to be that `!=` returns not-true if either value is `NULL`.  It is not appropriate.

You *could* fix your query as written.  However, that would only work for one match in the second table.  I would instead suggest `apply`:

```
UPDATE mc
SET mc.innings = ms.innings
FROM match_condition mc CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 ms.*
     FROM match_score ms
     WHERE ms.matchid = mc.matchid
     ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
    ) ms;
```

If you wanted to check on the `innings` value, you could use:

```
WHERE mc.innings IS NULL
```

Also note the use of *meaningful* table aliases.  Do not use arbitrary letters for represent tables.  Use table abbreviations!