# SQL Server SET ANSI_NULLS OFF does not work in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example 1

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_PROCEDURE]
    (@idate date = '2021-03-27')
AS
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

    INSERT INTO table_A
        SELECT * 
        FROM table_B 
        WHERE table_B.table_B_id NOT IN ('B1','B2')
END
```

When I exec `SP_PROCEDURE` example 1 No data from table_B to table_A

Example 2

```
DECLARE @idate date = '2021-03-27'
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

INSERT INTO table_A
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_B 
    WHERE table_B.table_B_id NOT IN ('B1','B2')
```

but example 2, I have data from table_B to table_A.

How to example 1 I have data from table_B to table_A

Comment: Why not fix your SQL and handle `NULL`s properly?

Comment: You should **NOT** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures - this is a Microsoft-reserved "special procedure" prefix which also has negative performance impacts - don't use that,

Comment: The documentation erroneously omits that `SET ANSI_NULLS` has no effect inside a stored procedure and is captured only on creation. This *is* mentioned in the documentation for [`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql). The docs do mention not to use this at all and write your queries so they work correctly regardless of this setting, and you should definitely follow that advice. This exists for backwards compatibility only (and even then one that's barely needed), not as any sort of workaround.

Comment: Regarding why, the setting in effect when the proc was altered/created is used at execution time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202766/where-clause-using-values-that-could-be-null/67203618#67203618 for how to compare nulls correctly, don't use `ANSI_NULLS OFF` it's basically deprecated