# Find day difference of last two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I'm trying to do is find the MAX date and do a datediff between the most recent date and the second to last date to create a single column for the difference in days. How do I get rid of the first two rows? I attempted to do a MAX by wrapping it another table, no luck.

**Sample Data:**

| ITEM ID | ITEM | LAST UPDATED | REASON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Pencil | 4/1/2020 | Correction |
| 123 | Pencil | 8/1/2020 | Correction |
| 123 | Pencil | 9/3/2020 | Correction |
| 456 | Highlighter | 5/1/2020 | Correction |
| 456 | Highlighter | 5/10/2020 | Correction |
| 789 | Pen | 10/1/2020 | Correction |
| 789 | Pen | 10/1/2020 | Correction |

**Expected Output:**

| ITEM ID | ITEM | LAST UPDATED | REASON | Days Diff Since Last Correction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Pencil | 9/3/2020 | Correction | 33 |
| 456 | Highlighter | 5/10/2020 | Correction | 9 |
| 789 | Pen | 10/20/2020 | Correction | 19 |

Here's what I've used so far:

```
SELECT 
       [Item_ID]
      ,[Item]
      ,[Last_Updated]
      ,[Reason]
      ,DATEDIFF(day,lag([Last_Updated],1) over(partition by [Item_ID] ORDER BY [Last_Updated] asc), [Last_Updated]) AS DAY_DIFF
  FROM [Table]
```

This is giving me the below:

```
Item_ID Item    Last_Updated    Reason  DAY_DIFF
123 Pencil  2020-04-01  Correction  NULL
123 Pencil  2020-08-01  Correction  122
123 Pencil  2020-09-03  Correction  33
456 Highlighter 2020-05-01  Correction  NULL
456 Highlighter 2020-05-10  Correction  9
789 Pen 2020-10-01  Correction  NULL
789 Pen 2020-10-20  Correction  19
```

Comment: I would personally do a stored proc for that, but since you seem to have the answer already I think you should do ORDER BY [last updated] DESC then just get the first row (TOP 1)

Comment: That would work, however, my real data is 300K rows and choosing the top 1 would give one Item ID out of the many

Comment: Your output is wrong cause this query won't produce it.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK . I will add on to this

Comment: Updated sample data, query and output.

Comment: Sample data as DDL+DML makes it *much* easier for people to assist.

Comment: Do you have an example of what that looks like or a guide? I'll make sure to do it next time. @DaleK

Comment: @Meowzz https://stackoverflow.com/a/69834257/1127428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.* from(
SELECT 
       [Item_ID]
      ,[Item]
      ,[Last_Updated]
      ,[Reason]
      ,datediff(day, lag([Last_Updated],1,Last_Updated)over (partition by [Item_ID] order by [Last_Updated]),[Last_Updated])  as 'Difference Between Last Correction',
row_number() over (partition by [Item_ID] order by [Last_Updated] desc) as rn
  FROM [TABLE]
)t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Why add a second answer? Just update and undelete your original?

Comment: No luck with this. Saying the datefdiff needs 3 arguments. Included a comma that may have been missing but now it says lag requires 'over' still.

Comment: @Meowzz could you test it again?

Comment: @FarshidShekari Ok this is close. But not sure why the day differences are populating as negative values. Going to play around with this more

Comment: @Meowzz because startDate bigger than end date, I fixed it.